# Aptik Doesn't Appear in Search Results

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04

I just performed a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04, and installed `Aptik` from the ppa shown in the output of `apt policy aptik`. The thing is that `Aptik` is not found when searching using the application launcher. Just nothing comes up. Given that the Aptik GUI is dependent on this mechanism, how can I resolve this or get the Aptik GUI back?

`apt policy aptik` Shows:

> `sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ apt policy aptik
>   aptik:
>     Installed: 18.5.2-0~201805120407~ubuntu18.04.1
>     Candidate: 18.5.2-0~201805120407~ubuntu18.04.1
>     Version table:
>    *** 18.5.2-0~201805120407~ubuntu18.04.1 500
>           500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Does "Install the `aptik-gtk` package and type aptik-gtk in a terminal" from https://github.com/teejee2008/aptik/issues/6#issuecomment-386788217

Comment: @DKBose Nice, that worked. If you post it as the answer, I'll accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the developer's comment on the [GitHub issues page for Aptik](https://github.com/teejee2008/aptik/issues/6#issuecomment-386788217), installing the `aptik-gtk` package will help resolve the issue.

Comment: This. As of this release, `aptik` is a terminal app, and `aptik-gtk` is the GUI. It confused me too.